# Left hand side expression increments even though exception is thrown

Tags: javascript

Given the following code snippet:

```js
const arr = [];
let pos = 0;

const fn = () => { throw 'foo'; };

try {
    arr[pos++] = fn();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(pos);
}
```

I was surprised to see that the value of `pos` was 1. Intuitively, I would have expected the RHS to be evaluated first, so when the exception is thrown `pos` will remain unmodified.

Could someone point to the relevant portions of the spec that covers this? Or otherwise explain the the behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ECMAScript 2015 clearly defines this behavior:](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> *AssignmentExpression<sub>[In, Yield]</sub> : LeftHandSideExpression<sub>[?Yield]</sub> = AssignmentExpression<sub>[?In, ?Yield]</sub>*
>
> 1. If *LeftHandSideExpression* is neither an *ObjectLiteral* nor an *ArrayLiteral*, then
>
>    a. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.
>
>    b. ReturnIfAbrupt(*lref*).
>
>    c. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
>
>    [...]

You can see that the left hand side expression is to be evaluated first, then the right hand side expression (*AssignmentExpression*).